# How to get POST parameters with wrong header

Tags: php

I am making a POST request from IE using [XDomainRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288060%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). XDomainRequest does not sent a Content-Type in his header and it is [not possible to set a custom header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657180/setting-headers-in-xdomainrequest-or-activexobjectmicrosoft-xmlhttp). I think this causes PHP to not place the post variables in `$_POST`.

I can see the parameters are send if I use `file_get_contents("php://input")` but I am not sure how to parse them correctly without breaking them. Is there a way to force PHP to collect the POST parameters? Or how can I get the variables safely?

I am using [this transport](https://github.com/jaubourg/ajaxHooks/blob/master/src/ajax/xdr.js) to get XDomainRequest in jQuery and make this call:

```
jQuery.post('http://domain.de/io/login', 'email=test2@stuff.de&password=xxx', function(response)
{
    if (console) console.log(response);
    alert('response: ' + objectToString(response));
});
```

On the PHP side I have:

```
print_r($_REQUEST, true);
echo file_get_contents("php://input");
```

Works fine with Firefox. But Firefox does not use the transport.

Comment: POST variables don't magically disappear, not even if some headers are or are not present. Please show the code how you issue the request.

Comment: `I think this causes PHP to not place the post variables in $_POST.` This false assertion is your weak link. Come back with facts! :)

Comment: It's not easy to cut out some example code. But how is it possible that php://input contains the variables and $_REQUEST does not? The only difference I can see is the request header I get from `getallheaders()`

Comment: Please see [Advanced handling of HTTP requests in PHP](https://gist.github.com/1028251) and http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php

Comment: @CodeCaster: See code above. The variables did not disappear. They just not in $_POST.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@hakre: Thanks a lot. Your [document](https://gist.github.com/1028251) describes what no one here belives:

> The body of the request is to be interpreted according to the
>   Content-Type header.

It also mentions [parse_str](http://php.net/manual/de/function.parse-str.php)() that does exactly what I needed.

Here my code to fill $_POST if it was not set by PHP:

```
if (count($_POST) == 0)
{
    $request_body = file_get_contents("php://input");
    parse_str($request_body, $_POST);
}
```

I would love to give you reputation for this but I don't know how. Anyway you just got +50 from me, so I hope that will be ok.

Answer (score -2):

As I can see in the [`jQuery.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) manual, the data parameter has to be in the following format:

```
jQuery.post('http://domain.de/io/login', {email: "test2@stuff.de", password: "xxx"}, function(response)
{
    if (console) console.log(response);
    alert('response: ' + objectToString(response));
});
```

Comment: From the manual: "A map or string". Works fine as string with Firefox.