# Empty $_POST without Content-type

Tags: php, javascript

If I make a POST request where the content-type is not set in the request header, the variable $_POST remains empty.

Question: How can I force PHP to fill $_POST?

I encountered the problem making an Javascript AJAX request using [XDomainRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288060%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) where you can not define any headers. Just to make it easier for you to understand the problem you can simulate the same effect without Javascript in PHP this way:

```
$data = 'test=1';

$fp = fsockopen('www.yourpage.org', 80, $errno, $errstr, 5);
fputs($fp, "POST /test_out.php HTTP/1.1\r\n");
fputs($fp, "Host: www.yourpage.org\r\n");
//fputs($fp, "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n");
fputs($fp, "Content-length: ". strlen($data) ."\r\n");
fputs($fp, "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");
fputs($fp, $data);

while(!feof($fp)) { echo fgets($fp, 128); }
fclose($fp);
```

test_out.php would be

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

Without the correct content-type the variables in $_POST *magically disappear*.

This is more an educational question. I am asking this because most people here can not imaging that the content-type has this effect. I was asked to 'come back with facts'. So here you go.

Comment: There's nothing magical about it. That's how PHP works (and any other CGI interpreter for that matter). See [php-src/main/rfc1867.c](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/main/rfc1867.c?revision=316373&view=markup) -- Not sure what your question is. Why do you want to omit the required header?

Comment: I don't want to. XDomainRequest does that and there is no way around it because you can not add custom headers. I marked the question with "Question:".

Comment: Awesome. Working on a php rest service.  Suddenly $_POST disappeared.  Yep.  No content type.  Took forever to figure out how to get $_POST back if we accept unique content types.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can override/inject the necessary header using Apache `mod_headers` if you have to. Or otherwise resort to manually reconstructing the $_POST array. (See also [userland multipart/form-data handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5561078/userland-multipart-form-data-handler))

If it's always urlencoded, simply read from `php://input` (Which contains the raw POST request body) and use `parse_str`:

```
parse_str(file_get_contents("php://input"), $_POST);
```

That should recreate the POST array, pretty much like PHP would do.

Comment: Greate, perfect answer! Last time I asked the [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8183397/how-to-get-post-parameters-with-wrong-header) I got -3 votes and +6 votes on wrong comments then they closed the question. Only one person (hakre) pointed in the right direction. I think it is sad when questions are closed because of a lack of knowledge.

Comment: Hmmm, okay. Small formulation issues often tick people off. -- But why did you ask it twice? It seems you already knew about the appropriate workaround.

Comment: Because I say many people didn't know about this and I wanted a not closed question about this. I learn a lot reading questions and I hope so do others. Also I think it was not fair how my other question was handled.