# How can I make cross-domain requests with custom headers without using XDomainRequest or XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain, xdomainrequest

I have a single page web application delivered from `www.example.com`. This web applications

- needs to make AJAX requests against another server named `api.example.com`
- it has to set certain header fields like `Authorization` when sending requests to `api.example.com`
- it has to be compatible with recent and not so recent browsers (for example IE >= 8)

All this works by handling CORS requests on api.example.com with Chrome (and other recent WebKit-based browsers) using `XMLHttpRequest`. [IE older than version 10](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673569%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#cors_xhr) doesn't implement CORS for `XMLHttpRequest` and instead provides the non-standard `XDomainRequest` object for cross-domain requests. But `XDomainRequest` does not implement a way to [set HTTP header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657180/setting-headers-in-xdomainrequest-or-activexobjectmicrosoft-xmlhttp) fields.

So my question is: How can I make cross-domain requests with custom headers without using `XDomainRequest` or `XMLHttpRequest`? What is the best practice workaround?

Edit: I have control over all involved servers (*.example.com).

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid there is no other way but to implement a proxy for this request in your application's server side. [An example](http://developer.yahoo.com/javascript/howto-proxy.html).

Comment: This is correct. You could always use an iframe and `postMessage` though.

Comment: So I assume there is at least one other way :)

Comment: I had no idea such useful method as postMessage existed, so thanks @idbehold. You'll need to have control over api.example.com, because you have to put the iframe content in that domain. Also it seems that you can only send strings with postMessage in IE.

Comment: For sending strings in IE you'll simply want to `JSON.encode()` when sending and then `JSON.decode()` when receiving.