# How can I set the content-type of XDomainRequest object?

Tags: javascript, http, xmlhttprequest, xdomainrequest

for XMLHttpRequest it is pretty easy:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', MyUrl, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
```

But how do I achieve this for XDomainRequest?

Comment: I dont think you can do that.. refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657180/setting-headers-in-xdomainrequest-or-activexobjectmicrosoft-xmlhttp

Comment: So you suggest that XDomainRequest always sends RAW data and no way to define the data-type I send?

Comment: That is correct. XDomainRequest is very limited, you can learn more about these limitations here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/05/13/xdomainrequest-restrictions-limitations-and-workarounds.aspx 

IE10 will have full support for CORS.

Comment: @SankalpMishra I think this question is ont the same as the one you have mentioned, in which the poster is trying to add a custom http header, while in this post, the poster is trying to change the value of a http header, like `Content-Type`

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to override the XMLHttpRequest content-type. You should set it correctly on the server e.g. for php:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

If this is not possible, then you can create a local proxy script which mirrors your crossdomain script with the correct header